# Поменять значения чётных и нечётных ячеек массива

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Есть задача: Объявите указатель на массив типа `int` и выделите память память для 12-ти элементов. Необходимо написать функцию, которая поменяет значения четных и нечетных ячеек массива. http://purecodecpp.com/archives/1284

Мой текущий код:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int *str=new int[12];
int n=1;

void sort(int *num)
{
    int b,i;
    bool c;
    c=true;
    for (i=0;i<=12; ){
        if((num[i]%2!=0)  (num[i+1]%2==0)) 
            {
                b=0;
                b=num[i];
                num[i]=num[i+1];
                num[i+1]=b;
                cout<<num[i]<<'_';
                i=i+2;
                c=false;
            }


        if(c) i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<=12;i++)
    {
        str[i]=n;
        n++;
    }
    sort (str);
    delete [] str;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Код либо не запускается/либо выводит только четные числа. Огромная просьба помочь.

Comment: Используйте отладчик...

Comment: @user186578 Четные и нечетные ячейки массива - это элементы с четными и нечетными индексами или это два последовательных элемента массива, первый из которых храним четное значение, а последующий - нечетное значение?

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете написать как рекурсивную функцию, так и итеративную функцию для перестановки соседних элементов с четными и нечетными индексами.

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как это сделать, используя соответствующие написанные программистом функции.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void recursive_swap( int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        int tmp = a[0];
        a[0] = a[1];
        a[1] = tmp;

        recursive_swap( a + 2, n - 2 );
    }
}

void iterative_swap( int a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; !( n < 2 ); n -= 2, i += 2 )
    {
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i+1];
        a[i+1] = tmp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 12;
    int *a = new int[N];

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) a[i] = std::rand() % N;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    recursive_swap( a, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    iterative_swap( a, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete []a;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
6 6 4 3 7 4 1 10 2 1 4 1 
6 6 3 4 4 7 10 1 1 2 1 4 
6 6 4 3 7 4 1 10 2 1 4 1
```

Данный фрагмент кода

```
int tmp = a[0];
a[0] = a[1];
a[1] = tmp;
```

можно было бы заменить на вызов стандартной функции `std::swap`, определенной в заголовке `<utility>`. Например

```
#include <utility>

//...

std::swap( a[0], a[1] );
```

Используя данный подход, показанный в функциях вы можете менять местами не только соседние элементы массива, но и элементы массива, отстоящие друг от друга на заданное число.

Обобщенная функция может выглядеть следующим образом

```
void iterative_swap( int a[], size_t n, size_t m )
{
    if ( !( m < n ) || ( m < 1 ) ) return;

    ++m;

    for ( size_t i = 0; !( n < m ); n -= m, i += m )
    {
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i + m - 1];
        a[i + m - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void iterative_swap( int a[], size_t n, size_t m )
{
    if ( !( m < n ) || ( m < 1 ) ) return;

    ++m;

    for ( size_t i = 0; !( n < m ); n -= m, i += m )
    {
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i + m - 1];
        a[i + m - 1] = tmp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 12;
    int *a = new int[N];

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) a[i] = std::rand() % N;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {        
        iterative_swap( a, N, i );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    delete []a;
}
```

Вывод на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом

```
2 1 0 9 1 8 4 2 2 1 11 5 

1 2 9 0 8 1 2 4 1 2 5 11 
9 2 1 1 8 0 1 4 2 11 5 2 
1 2 1 9 4 0 1 8 2 11 5 2 
4 2 1 9 1 11 1 8 2 0 5 2 
11 2 1 9 1 4 2 8 2 0 5 1 
2 2 1 9 1 4 11 8 2 0 5 1 
8 2 1 9 1 4 11 2 2 0 5 1 
2 2 1 9 1 4 11 2 8 0 5 1 
0 2 1 9 1 4 11 2 8 2 5 1 
5 2 1 9 1 4 11 2 8 2 0 1 
1 2 1 9 1 4 11 2 8 2 0 5
```

В этом выводе первая строка

```
1 2 9 0 8 1 2 4 1 2 5 11
```

это обмен смежных элементов.

Вторая строка

```
9 2 1 1 8 0 1 4 2 11 5 2
```

это обмен элементов через один элемент и т.д.

Comment: А `recursive_swap()` это с целью посмотреть на stack overflow для больших массивов?

Comment: @avp Это для целей изучения языка.

Comment: Если он (пока еще) пишет `for(int i=0;i<=12;i++)` для заполнения массива из 12 элементов, то изучение рекурсии ничего хорошего ему не даст (вряд ли он сможет осознать этот алгоритм).

Comment: @avp Во-первых, сообщения форума читают разные люди, а не только тот человек, кто задал вопрос. Во-вторых, новые знания всегда полезны.

Comment: @avp Что касается того, что он пишет for(int i=0;i<=12;i++) , то вы точно также сами пишите.a[i] = a[i + 1] при i равном N-1;. Так что это не является причиной, чтобы не познакомиться с рекурсивной функцией, которая к тому же имеет хвостовую рекурсию. Так что переполнение стека совершенно не обязательно.

Comment: Странная какая-то обобщенная функция -- дырявая. Например, для N=12, step=2 оставляет необмененными элементы 1,4,7,10. Для чего такое может быть нужно? Логичным для шага 2 представляются обмены `0<->2,1<->3,4<->6,5<->7,8<->10,9<->11`. (хотя, и это для чего, не передставляю)

Comment: @avp Это уже как вы решите сами. Например, поиск слов в строке может следовать алгоритму, когда следующее совпадающее слово ищется с позиции после найденного слова. А можно искать следующее слово со следующего после первого символа. например при поиске слова "AA"  в строке "AAA" при первом подходе будет найдено одно слово, а при втором - два слова. Точно также и здесь.

Answer (score 1):

Задача поменять четные и нечетные позиции, а не значения.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int array_size = 12;
int *str = new int[array_size];
int n = 1;

void sort(int *num, int size)
{
    int b, i;
    for (i = 0; i < (size & ~1); i += 2)
    {
        b = num[i];
        num[i] = num[i + 1];
        num[i + 1] = b;
    }
}

void print_array(int* arr, int size) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << str[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) 
    {
        str[i] = n;
        n++;
    }
    print_array(str, array_size);
    sort(str, array_size);
    print_array(str, array_size);
    delete[] str;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваша реализация функции sort некорректна.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow почему? Не проверяю входные параметры?

Comment: Например, в этом предложении num[i] = num[i + 1]; вы  можете выйти за границу массива, когда size является нечетным числом.

Comment: В задаче вообще говорилось про 12 чисел. Хорошо, исправил.

Comment: Нет, вы не исправили. Вы заменили один баг на другой.:) Выражение i < size & ~1; эквивалентно выражению  ( i  < size ) & ~1;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow приоритеты операторов - не мой конек.

Comment: Я также часто сам допускаю подобную ошибку, когда использую битовые операции и логические операции :)

Comment: Почему неправильно if((num[i]%2!=0) II (num[i+1]%2==0)) ?ведь с помощью этой конструкции проверяется на(1ое число должно быть нечетным ,а второе четное ).Я понимаю что это код проверит 11 й и 12 й элемент,переставит их местами и сошлется на 13 элемент что наполнит цикл for ложью,и тот не выполнится,если я конечно правильно понимаю.И что значит конструкция i < (size & ~1);???

Answer (score 1):

У Вас всюду основная проблема в условии завершения цикла `<= 12`.

Элементы массива индексируются с 0, поэтому в массиве из  12 элементов индекс последнего -- **11!**.
Соответственно циклы д.б. вида

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
  ...
```

Тогда естественный цикл обмена значениями четных (0 -- четное) с нечетными элементов будет следующим

```
int N = 12; // размер массива, просто чтобы показать цикл общего вида
if (N > 1) 
  for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i += 2) { // скачем по четным, меняем со следующим
    int t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[i + 1];
    a[i + 1] = t;
  }
```

Очевидно, что работает как с четным, так и с нечетным размером массива (в т.ч. с INT_MAX).

Comment: Имейте в виду, что помимо выходя за границу массива в предложении a[i] = a[i + 1]; ваша функция все равно некорректная в общем случае.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, спасибо, поправил для нечетного размера массивов (вот ведь, виноват... короче, давая примеры кода их **всегда надо проверять**) / Кстати, что кроме этого Вы имели в виду под `все равно некорректная в общем случае`?

Comment: Да, функция все равно некорректна в общем случае. Рассмотрите ситуацию, когда N равно INT_MAX.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, `INT_MAX: 2147483647  n = 2147483646` и что? Последний i + 1 будет 2147483645 / Никаких переполнений не вижу.

Comment: Я имел в виду первоначальную функцию.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, а вы комментарии (в которых Вам отвечают)  повнимательней читайте.

Comment: Недостаток этого подхода еще заключается в том, что он привязан к магическому числу 2. Если, допустим, нужно поменять местами элементы через один элемент, то функцию придется полностью переписывать.

Comment: С этим Вы, похоже, правы. Неохота придумывать обобщения (и  проверять их). А вот с вычислением `n = (N % 2) ? N - 1 : N;` я погорячился. Все значительно проще, достаточно бежать до N - 1  (сейчас поправлю).